# Can I get Magnesium into gas at room temperature?

Tags: atomic-physics

This might sit squarely at the intersection of physics, chemistry, and quantum mechanics.

I make gas discharge tubes.  One color that evades me is green.  Apparently Magnesium will do this, but I don't know how to get it into the gas state at room temperature without a lot of temperature.

Is this even possible?

The tubes I make run from a few microns to several torr, operate at room temperature, and are excited from one end by high frequency AC.   I don't have any mechanism to create much heat in the tube, and it wouldn't be a good idea anyway.

Alternatively, is there a way to get to a green discharge without the Xenon Nitrogen mix?  That one is apparently hard to get working, and I have yet to get a reasonable cost source for Xenon.

Comment: I suspect the partial pressure of Mg at room temperature is vanishingly small.  Why don't you search around so-called "neon tube sign" manufacturers to see what they use to create green discharge tubes?

Comment: Google finds ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19650008905.pdf which has measured values and the fit to the vapor pressure of Mg. Extrapolating to room temperature (293K) yields a vapor pressure of about $10^{-17}$Torr. I would follow the advice of @CarlWitthoft. (Or, look into Argon or Krypton - those lase in the green quite nicely).

Comment: Neon sign people create green with mercury discharge and a phosphor on the tube like florescent lights.